# ¿Cómo enviar sms desde la consola usando adb?

Tags: android, sms, adb

He estado indagando principalmente en stackoverflow.com y la mayoria coincide en este código:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:<telefono> --es sms_body "<mensaje>" --ez exit_on_sent true
adb shell input keyevent 22
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

Donde telefono es el número al cual deseo enviarle el SMS y mensaje es el cuerpo del mismo. El problema viene dado porque adb ejecuta correctamente la primera línea de código y ejecuta el Intent encargado de enviar el SMS, establece el destinatario y escribe el cuerpo del mensaje, pero no lo envía, cosa que supongo que debería hacer en las próximas 2 líneas. Aclarar que estoy empleando mi celular un Sony XPERIA ZL C6502 con Android Jelly Bean 4.2, Windows 10 64bits y adb 1.0.31.

Otras opciones sería crear una aplicación que enviara el sms y estuviera a la escucha. Y posteriormente ejecutarla desde el adb y enviarle los datos necesarios para que envie el sms, pero no pienso que deba hacerla ya que si adb lo hace es trabajar por gusto.

Cualquier ayuda será más que recibida, ah también usé este comando:

```
adb shell service call isms 5 s16 "com.android.mms" s16 "+5353715814" s16 "+01000000000" s16 "Hello world !" i32 0 i32 0
```

Y me devolvió el siguiente mensaje

```
Result: Parcel(fffffffc ffffffff   '........')
```

Answer (score -1):

A mi me funciono mandar mensajes pero desde dentro de la terminal.

`adb shell
am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:[telefono] --es sms_body "mensaje>" --ez exit_on_sent true; input keyevent 22; input keyevent 66`

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. Saludos.